# How to ensure that the width of a widget doesnt exceed the width of the window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently working with a python GUI. The label widget reads its content from a file and sometimes the strings become longer than the width of the window and as such some strings goes missing in the GUI. How do I correct that?
I also have a similar problem with radio button widgets and I would like them to display under each other. eg.

```
(a) Boy
(c) Girl
(d) Us
```

Here is my code:

```
class appWin(Frame):
    def __init__(self,q,i,oj):
        Frame.__init__(self,oj)
        self.i = i
        self.q = q
        question = StringVar()
        question.set(self.q)
        qw = Label(oj,textvariable = question).pack(side = 'left')
    def options(a):
        ansVar = StringVar()
        ansVar.set(None)
        obj = Radiobutton(oj, variable = ansVar , text = a, value = a).pack(side = 'left')

a = cbt.a[0]
q = cbt.q[0]
i = cbt.q[1]
j = cbt.a[1]
oj = Tk()
oj.title('Ojonjo CBT 1.0')
oj.geometry('600x200+100+100')
window = appWin(q,a,oj)
w = window.pack
a,b,c,d,e,f = j.split(',')
options(a)
options(b)
options(c)
oj.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make the widgets not grow (and thus, characters longer than the widget won't be visible), or are you asking how to get the contents of a label to wrap?

Comment: Wrap is the word, I want the label to wrap in the window

Comment: Does the following link help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25933962/7432